# How to apply Quill.js to an already content editable element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, quill

### The problem:

I have to use the Delta and Event features of [Quill.js](http://quilljs.com/) to provide some contextual dropdowns on specific keywords within the Gmail Composer (on gmail.com) in a chrome extension.

The problem is that the Gmail Composer already has a content editable element. When I apply Quill.js to it, I end up with another `contenteditable` element within the gmail composer element. With a simple *backspace* the Quill.js editor actually gets deleted and the functionality of quill is pretty much broken in many other ways.

I can't remove the Gmail Composer's editor because then I remove basic Gmail functions like Attachments, Links, Emoticons etc. On the other hand I have to use Quill.js to implement some features.

### Example

Here is a simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/vdaqrsrw/1/:

[image: Quill.js added to an already contenteditable element]

When initiating Quill on the `#editor` it creates the `#ql-editor-1` element within the `#editor` element that already has `contenteditable` set - so now we have 2 contenteditable elements nested in each other that breaks the toolbar and general functionality of the editable area:

[image]

### The Question

Is there a way to apply [Quill.js](http://quilljs.com/) to an already content editable area without the nesting problems? Are there any other ways to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Quill was designed and built to be a standalone editor.

Comment: Is it possible to edit the sourcecode to avoid this? Or it would be overkill?

Comment: There's nothing in the source that *prevents* this but there's also nothing that *supports* it. To add support you'd probably have to change a lot of code, though the boundaries are also possible (very little code or changing so much it's a different code base).